# Laravel 8: Request cookies are not decrypted when dd()'ed with maintenance mode enabled

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

So when an app operates normally, calling `dd(request()->cookies);` literally everywhere, shows a nice array of decrypted cookies that are glued to the request.

Unfortunately when I `php artisan down` and refresh the page I was, the dump shows me the exact same array but values are encrypted, therefore some logic that relies on cookie's value is broken.

I assume this is a normal Laravel behaviour as only essential functionality is available.

Still is there a possibility to get correctly decrypted cookies when maintenance mode is turned on?

Comment: did you change the APP_KEY value in .env between the two server starts ?

Comment: Nope, I did not.

Comment: are you sure ? I'm saying this since the encryption done on the cookies is using that variable as salt, and changing it is the only was to break it. Or maybe you have another (laravel?) installation that is served on the same hostname that is setting its own cookies using its own APP_KEY